# getting this error executing Java applet

Tags: java, applet

Getting this error executing a Java applet. I am running JRE 8u65.
Code was compiled against JDK 1.6 source

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>               network: Checking for update at: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar
>       network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar with
>   proxy=DIRECT
>       network: Connecting http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
>       network: Updating file at: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\securitypack.jar
>   from url: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Can you open https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar in a browser?

Comment: No I get 
This page can’t be displayed


Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com  again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator.

I do have those enabled in IE btw

Comment: same with FireFox and Chrome

Comment: also getting this

`code
network: Connecting http://sv.symcd.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://sv.symcd.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Failing over to CRLs: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://sv.symcd.com
network: Connecting http://sv.symcb.com/sv.crl with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://sv.symcb.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Revocation Status Unknown
com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://sv.symcd.com`